# Set the Size of a UICollectionViewCell based on the screen width and the number of columns Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am building an application using the `Xamarin.iOS`. A the first screen of the app I have used a `UICollectionView` to display a number of categories. I want the categories to be displayed in two columns, but here there a problem. I set the size of the cell manually on the `storyBoard.In` small screen like `iPhone 3.5` inch, only one column appears, meanwhile in larger screens like `iPhone 6` or `6Plus` two columns appear but with a lot of space between the columns.

The table View has a method that we can override in `TableViewSource`,`GetRowHeight`. Is there a way to set the Size of a `collectionViewCell` based on the screen width and the number of columns.

This is the way I have implemented the CollectionView in My App:

SectionViewSource.cs

```
public class SectionViewSource: UICollectionViewSource
    {
        public List<SectionCategory> rows { get; set; }
        public ViewController owner { get; set;}

        public SectionViewSource (List<SectionCategory> _rows, ViewController _owner)
        {
            rows = _rows;
            owner = _owner;

        }

        public override nint NumberOfSections (UICollectionView collectionView)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public override nint GetItemsCount (UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
        {
            return rows.Count;
        }

        public override bool ShouldHighlightItem (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override void ItemHighlighted (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = (SectionViewCell)collectionView.CellForItem (indexPath);
            cell.mainLabel.Alpha = 0.5f;



        }

        public override bool CanPerformAction (UICollectionView collectionView, Selector action, NSIndexPath indexPath, NSObject sender)
        {

                return true;
        }

        public override void PerformAction (UICollectionView collectionView, Selector action, NSIndexPath indexPath, NSObject sender)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("code to perform action");

        }

        public override void ItemUnhighlighted (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {

            var cell = (SectionViewCell)collectionView.CellForItem (indexPath);
            cell.mainLabel.Alpha = 1.0f;

        }

        public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = (SectionViewCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (SectionViewCell.CellID, indexPath);

            cell.UpdateCell (rows [indexPath.Row].sectionName,rows [indexPath.Row].sectionUrlImage);

            return cell;
        }
    }
```

SectionViewCell.cs

```
public class SectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell
    {
        public UILabel mainLabel;
        public UIImageView _imageView;
        public static NSString CellID = new NSString("customCollectionCell");

        [Export ("initWithFrame:")]
        public SectionViewCell (CGRect frame) : base(frame)
        {
            BackgroundView = new UIView { BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange };

            ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

            _imageView = new UIImageView ();
            mainLabel = new UILabel ();

            mainLabel.TextColor = UIColor.White;

            ContentView.AddSubviews (new UIView[] { _imageView, mainLabel });
        }



        public void UpdateCell (string text, string url) {

            mainLabel.Text = text;
            mainLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation;
            mainLabel.Lines = 2; 
            mainLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName("Optima-Bold", 18f);

            ImageService.LoadUrl(url).Into(_imageView);
            _imageView.Frame = new CGRect (0, 0, ContentView.Bounds.Width, ContentView.Bounds.Height);
            mainLabel.Frame = new CGRect (10, 10, ContentView.Bounds.Width-20, 40);

        }

    }
```

ViewController.cs

```
sectionGrid.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(SectionViewCell), SectionViewCell.CellID);
sectionGrid.Source = new SectionViewSource (sectionCategories,this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the CollectionViewLayout like so:

```
// Flow Layout
var flowLayout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout (){
    ItemSize = new CGSize ((float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width/2.0f, (float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width/2.0f),
    HeaderReferenceSize = new CGSize (100, 100),
    SectionInset = new UIEdgeInsets (0,0,0,0),
    ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical,
    MinimumInteritemSpacing = 0, // minimum spacing between cells
    MinimumLineSpacing = 0 // minimum spacing between rows if ScrollDirection is Vertical or between columns if Horizontal
};

simpleCollectionViewController = new UICollectionViewController (flowLayout);
```

creates some thing like this:

[image]

---

**Update**

you could try this:

```
var flowLayout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout (){
    ItemSize = new CGSize ((float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width/2.0f, (float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width/2.0f),
    HeaderReferenceSize = new CGSize (100, 100),
    SectionInset = new UIEdgeInsets (0,0,0,0),
    ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical,
    MinimumInteritemSpacing = 0, // minimum spacing between cells
    MinimumLineSpacing = 0 // minimum spacing between rows if ScrollDirection is Vertical or between columns if Horizontal
};

sectionGrid.PerformBatchUpdates (() => {
    sectionGrid.CollectionViewLayout.InvalidateLayout ();
    sectionGrid.SetCollectionViewLayout (flowLayout, false);
});
```

Comment: I am not using an `UICollectionViewController`. I am just using `UICollectionView` because I have other view inside the screen.

Comment: I have updated the question describing the situation and what I have done. If there is possible can you help me pointing out what I have done wrong, or where should I use our solution.

Comment: Cool i'll take a look and see what i can do

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot :) I made also some changes in the Main.Storyboard, but at the end it worked perfectly. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Cool, yeah it can be tricky to do more dynamic layouts in the storyboard.